# Trigger AWS Autoscale automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I have an Autoscale Web Application in AWS. When I don't use it, I terminated EC2 instances automatically with Lambda (with Cloudwatch). But I couldn't find an automatic structure to trigger it again.

What I have tried.

- I tried with Cloudwatch but I have to wait after the first request. It's not suitable for my setup.
- I trigger ELB by redirecting the requests coming to port 80 to Lambda and then redirect my main project 443, but it didn't seem very healthy.

If you have other suggestions or services I can use, can you share them?

Comment: What is your actual architecture? Are you saying that you have an Elastic Load Balancer in front of a variable number of Amazon EC2 instances? Are the EC2 instances in an EC2 Auto Scaling group? If so, why are you using an AWS Lambda function to terminate them instead of using an Alarm associated with the Auto Scaling group? What do you want to happen when there is no traffic -- do you want _all_ of the instances to be terminated, even if this means you won't be able to serve traffic when a request does eventually arrive?

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility that EC2s are not included in the AutoScale group? So can you set the Desired capacity to 0 with an alarm? If the servers are not in use, I terminate all instances in Autoscale and try to trigger it again when a request comes in.

Comment: When you say "if the servers are not in use" do you mean when there's no active traffic? If no active traffic, set desired/min to 0. If a request comes in, set desire/min to # instances? You can use the ALB's ActiveConnectionCount with CW Alarm, then trigger the lambda based on if the count if below or above your threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it should trigger when get first request. So Cloudwatch will not work in this scenario because will calculate this metric in 1 min with in 1 datapoint. I need to  trigger immediately/

Answer (score 0):

If you want an **immediate response** to traffic, then you **should not scale to zero instances**. Launching or Starting an instance takes time, which probably won't meet your requirement. Therefore, you should always **keep a minimum of one instance** running at all times.

It is possible to create a **warm pool** of instances that can be quickly added to the Auto Scaling group. These instances can be kept in a Stopped or Hibernated state to reduce costs, but they will still take time to launch. See: [Warm pools for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools.html)

The typical pattern is:

- Create a **Scale-Out Alarm** that can detect when the current instances in the Auto Scaling group are above desired capacity. Use the Alarm to trigger an Auto Scaling policy that adds another instance to the group.
- Create a **Scale-In Alarm** that can detect when there are too many resources, which means you are over-paying for the app. Use the Alarm to trigger an Auto Scaling policy that removes an instance from the group. You can specify a **minimum** size for the Auto Scaling group, such as specifying that there should always be a minimum of one instance.

A general rule is **"Scale-Out quickly, Scale-In slowly":**

- You would want the **Scale-Out Alarm** to respond reasonably quickly (eg based on a metric over a few minutes). However, be careful because responding too quickly to a usage spike might add capacity that isn't needed. This would cause the Auto Scaling group to 'flap' -- that is, adding and removing capacity too quickly.
- To prevent flapping, configure the **Scale-In Alarm** to wait some time before removing resources (eg using a metric over a 15-minute period or longer). It is often better to have some under-utilised resources rather than continually adding and removing resources, so go slowly when deciding to scale-in.

You mention "I terminated EC2 instances automatically with Lambda (with CloudWatch)". However, EC2 Auto Scaling does not use Lambda functions. Instead, it uses **CloudWatch Alarms** to monitor metrics and **Auto Scaling policies** to determine how to respond to Alarms. You can, of course, create your own auto-scaling capabilities using Lambda, but you would miss out on the many capabilities of [EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html).

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for your message, I already know all details on AWS. I just need to create custom structure. Anyway, I will do with my way. Thanks.